# How to make cucumber read Scenario Outline Example values contain single quotes

Tags: cucumber

```
......
And I will see the providerName <providerName> for Providerone
.......
Examples:
| providerName          | 
| 'St. Edward's School' |
```

The above scenario outline generated the below test stub. which depicts that the first value within the single quote is taken into consideration by cucumber. How to declare the example statement in cucmber so that it reads the entire value as 1 string

```
When('I will see the providerName {string}s School\' for Providerone', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return 'pending';
```

Comment: Try quoting with double - `"St. Edward's School"` or maybe escape the single quote - `'St. Edward\'s School'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the provider name in the step:

```
And I will see the providerName "<providerName>" for Providerone
```

Then the examples table doesn't need any extraneous quotes:

```
Examples:
| providerName        | 
| St. Edward's School |
```